# How do I disable the menu access shortcuts in xfce4-terminal?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, xfce, xfce4-terminal

In xfce4-terminal, the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key with a letter of one of the menu items is a shortcut for entering that menu item: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> for **F**ile, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> for **E**dit, and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> for T**a**bs.  How do I change this behaviour?  I would like to use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> in another application (irssi) and disable this shortcut within xfce4-terminal.  I have already looked at Settings -> Window Manager -> Keyboard, but this shortcut is not listed there.  How can I change or disable it?

Answer (score 7):

Within xfce4-terminal, go to Edit -> Prefences -> Advanced, and in the section "Shortcuts", check the button for "Disable all menu access keys (such as Alt+f)".

This will disable all <kbd>Alt</kbd>+-menu access keys and thus make them available for other applications.